# Accessing Entry widget created using for loop

Tags: python, tkinter

An array of Entries was created using the following code

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

height = 5
width = 5

delta=0

for i in range(height): #Rows
  for j in range(width): #Columns
    b = Entry(root, text="",width=8)
    b.grid(row=i, column=j)

mainloop()
```

How do I access each Entry to update its value ( using StringVar - for example ) ?

Comment: Why not store each entry in a list?

Comment: @SamChats A GUI is updated every few seconds

Comment: Sorry, I miss your point. Does that imply you can't use lists?

Comment: Perhaps I miss yours. Can you explain?

Comment: Instead of just `b = Entry(root, text="",width=8)`, you can do something like `entries.append(b)` after that line and then access each entry by doing `entries[3].do_something()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a list of lists for your `Entry` widgets.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

height = 5
width = 5

delta=0

entries = []

for i in range(height): #Rows
  newrow = []
  for j in range(width): #Columns
    b = Entry(root, text="",width=8)
    b.grid(row=i, column=j)
    newrow.append(b)
  entries.append(newrow)

mainloop()
```

You could then address individual entries as e.g. `entries[2][4]`.

**Edit:** To edit the text of entry widget `e`, first use `e.delete(0, END)` to clear it, and then use `e.insert(0, "new text")` to insert new text.

**Edit2:** Alternatively, you could store the StringVars in a list of lists instead of the widgets...

Comment: thanks for answers. I used your code, and it worked OK, but since it is not addressing StringVar, I didn't succeed to add text after creation of GUI

Comment: You don't necessarily *require* stringvars. You can edit the contents of the `Entry` widget as shown in the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first declare the `StringVar` variable:

`myvar = StringVar()`

Then in your loop whenever you want to check to content of the variable use the `get()` method.

`x = myvar.get()`

Now `x` will hold the value. You can also perform a bool test with `if`

```
if myvar.get():
     print(myvar.get())
```

In that if statement the program checks if there is data in the var. If not it will move on

Looking at it again you should also declare the `StringVar()` in your button. Like so:

```
b = Button(text='clickme', texvariable=myvar)
```

Look [Here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) for more info

Comment: How can change the value of cell 5,1 for example?

Comment: What do you mean? It is hard to say with out knowing what your trying to accomplish. The user interacting with the gui will change the value right? The get method just updates the value that the user entered

Comment: I'll try to explain: I create a 5X5 Entry matrix in a GUI ( I could use Label as well for that purpose, but for later use i prefer using Entry ). I wish to display on GUI my 5 TASKS ( columns ) and their status: enable/ disable, on-time, off- time, device to operate etc...
every second those values inside Entries are changed ... that is what I want to display

Comment: What changes those values? If the change is not coming from a user but rather from software you won't be using the entry widget.

Comment: it can be a physical button that changes on.off state or a scheduled task manager. the GUI (this part of it )will display those state and counters.

Comment: This question is about addressing entry widgets created in a loop. Your answer doesn't address that.

Comment: @BryanOakley because I traded multiple comments with GUY .D and the problem has since morphed a little. It was aimed at helping him understand grabbing variables. Thanks for the downvote though ;)

Comment: @Joe: don't take the downvote personally. It is a vote on the value of this answer to the question being asked, not a vote on you personally. Plus, the answer implies that a `StringVar` is required, which is not true. This answer simply does not answer the question that was asked.